# boost::serialization throwing "input stream error" on base class ptr XML serialization

Tags: boost, xml-serialization, boost-serialization

Am I doing something wrong here? If I take the comments out that serialize the base first it works, otherwise I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
    what():  input stream error
Aborted
```

Here is the code:

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() {};

    int i1 = 10;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & make_nvp("int", i1);
    }
};
struct B : A
{
    virtual ~B() {};

    float f1 = 5.0F

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
        ar & make_nvp("float", f1);
    }
};
struct C : A
{
    virtual ~C() {};

    long l1 = 24;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
        ar & make_nvp("long", l1);
    }
};

//Why do these need to be wrappers??
namespace boost
{
namespace serialization
{
template<> struct is_wrapper<A*> : mpl::true_ {};
template<> struct is_wrapper<A> : mpl::true_ {};
template<> struct is_wrapper<const A> : mpl::true_ {};
}
}

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(A);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(C)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //A* a = new A();
    A* b = new B();
    A* c = new C();
    //A* a1 = nullptr;
    A* a2 = nullptr;
    A* a3 = nullptr;

    ostringstream ostream;
    xml_oarchive oarchive(ostream);

    oarchive << /*BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a) <<*/ BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b) << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(c);

    istringstream istream(ostream.str());
    xml_iarchive iarchive(istream);

    iarchive >> /*BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a1) >>*/ BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a2) >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a3);

    //delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
    //delete a1;
    delete a2;
    delete a3;
}
```

The same code works in both cases for the text and binary archives...

**EDIT:** This is using Boost 1.53 and GCC 4.8 w/ std=c++11

Comment: `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a)` makes an xml item named "a". It looks like you first create items named "b", "c", and then try to read "a1", "a2" that do not exist?

Comment: If that were a problem I would expect the un-commented case to fail, it does not. I'm guessing the whole nvp thing is ignored with base class pointers to derived classes, at least in the de-serialization side? If you had to match up the names, that kind of defeats the purpose...